# ReferenceError: Cannot access store before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, axios

I have this `store/index.ts`

```
export const storeRedux = createStore(
  persistReducer(ReduxPersistConfig, rootReducer),
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
);
```

And have this implementation to access the token outside of component

```
//api.ts

import axios from 'axios';
import { storeRedux } from 'store';

let token;

const listener = () => {
  token = storeRedux.getState().user.token;
};

storeRedux.subscribe(listener);

// console.log(() => getAPI());

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/api/security',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
 
});
```

If I'll add a setTimeout to wrap the `getState()` then everything will be alright.

Is there any other solution since store is already separated just like in this
[article](https://daveceddia.com/access-redux-store-outside-react/#option-3-use-middleware-and-intercept-an-action)

Comment: You should check whether `storeRedux.getState().user` is defined, then you can access `storeRedux.getState().user.token`, although it is most likely easier to either place this into a component or to extract the token acquiring/saving out of redux.

Comment: even if I add check like this if (storeRedux) {} it still has an error

Comment: Do you have any other files that EXPORT your store? For example, do you have a component somewhere that imports store from your root component. That can trigger this error.

Comment: I'm just exporting it in store/index.ts

Comment: Which line do you get the ReferenceError? Could you show the code which you attempt using `setTimeout` and how you import the store to pass it into store's `Provider` in `App` component? [Here's 1 potential answer](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/167)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but question w/o answer sores my eye.

You have to assure the order of execution of the dependent code, you need to register listener once store is initiated. You can do this for example with the init method:

```
// api.ts
import { AnyAction, Store, Unsubscribe } from "redux";
import axios from 'axios';

let token;

export const initApi = (store:Store<TState, AnyAction>):Unsubscribe => {
  return store.subscribe(()=>{
    token = store.getState().user.token;
  })
}


export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/api/security',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
 
});
```

**Note** The `TState` describes your state e.g.

```
export type TState = {
  // ...
  user: { token: string; }
}
```

now, you can use it after store is initiated

```
// store/index.ts
import { initApi } from '../location/to/api.ts'; 

const storeRedux = createStore(
  persistReducer(ReduxPersistConfig, rootReducer),
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
);


initApi(storeRedux);

export { storeRedux };
```