# How access redux state outside react component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am starting learning redux and face some issue,
I want to configure axios interceptor for set jwt token every request but token is store in authSlice
, I was read a article : [https://daveceddia.com/access-redux-store-outside-react/](https://stackoverflow.com)

It was working fine

```
import axios from "axios";
import store from "../global-state/store";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
const state = store.getState();
const token = state.auth.token;

axios.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    config.headers.Authorization = token ? `token ${token}` : "";
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// Add response interceptor (example: handling common errors)
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    //  handle successful responses
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    // handle errors globally
    if (error.status == 401) {
      window.location.href = "/login";
    }
    if (error.response.status == 403) {
      window.location.href = "/access-denied";
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default axios;
```

but when I try to add another state

it was cause error

```
store.ts:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'counterReducer' before initialization
    at store.ts:11:14
```

code look like

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
    counter: counterReducer,
  },
});
```

Comment: Have you accidentally created a dependency cycle? In other words, is the file where `counterReducer` is declared and exported trying to import the `store` object for some purpose? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] with all relevant code you are working with?

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63461777/referenceerror-cannot-access-store-before-initialization/77638946#77638946), the question looks the same as yours